# Building libgdx default test project for iOS on Mac requires the Android SDK?

Tags: ios, libgdx

I created the default "test" project using the Project Generator, then copied the project to my Mac Mini, opened it in IntelliJ (with latest RoboVM installed), and ran gradle task "launchIPadSimulator" under the :ios project. Doing so seems to require to have the Android SDK set up on the Mac, but I only want to build for iOS on the Mac:

```
CODE: SELECT ALL
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':android'.
> SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.
```

How can I get around this? Do I really have to install the Android SDK just to do an iOS build? (I do want to build the Android portion on my Windows machine; just not on the Mac.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the multi-project gradle project generated by the Project Generator (which *is* indeed a good way to organize the projects), there does not appear to be a way to bypass the configuration step that, in the case of the Android sub-project, requires the Android SDK to be installed, and the easiest way to install that is by installing Android Studio and using its SDK Manager.

- Install Android Studio for Mac
- Open Android Studio
- Once it does its initial downloads, HAXM installation, etc. and you get to the project New/Open/etc screen, click the cog labeled "Configure" and select "SDK Manager"

  - Check the checkbox for the Android API Level needed by your project (current recommended is API 27, whereas Studio automatically installed 28)

    - Click "Apply"
- Open Terminal, cd to your project's root directory, and enter `./gradlew ios:launchIOSDevice` or `./gradlew ios:launchIPhoneSimulator` to build and run the app.